# Machine Learning : Which algorithm is better for detecting ships sailing in the sea from video stream?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I am working on a project by which I will try to detect ships in the sea from a moving camera in the sea. I can't figure out which algorithm is going to be better to use.

I found two resources:

The first one: http://scholarcommons.usf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1233&context=etd

The second one is to use haar like feature algorithm to detect ships.
which one is better and If there's a better way I can start with, what is it ?

Comment: try https://github.com/ShaoqingRen/faster_rcnn

Comment: You may want to have a look at what has been done in the "Right Whale Recognition" competition on Kaggle. The best two submissions explain their approaches [here](http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/02/04/noaa-right-whale-recognition-winners-interview-2nd-place-felix-lau/) and [here](http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/01/29/noaa-right-whale-recognition-winners-interview-1st-place-deepsense-io/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specific algorithms to detect "ships" or "things in the sea" nor papers related with that.

I would apply a cascade of algorithms over the bounding boxes (like [viola-jones](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/EE148-2005-Spring/pprs/viola04ijcv.pdf)). If you have a GPU, you can use CNNs to get a state of the art performance. Anyway, the main problem here on both cases is to get a good dataset of "ships" to train your algorithm. You can either build your own dataset of construct your own using severals existing datasets (like ImageNet, CIFAR,... [Datasets for deep learning](http://deeplearning.net/datasets/))

Also you can significantly reduce the number of hypothesis using [selective search](http://koen.me/research/pub/uijlings-ijcv2013-draft.pdf) instead of the typical fixed-sliding window.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to follow up on Carl Vondrick’s work. Several papers of his, talk about various video tasks. I think most people are interested in doing event classification or action predictions from videos. I think his papers are a good start. His github repo doesn’t yet have any code on video classification, but you can watch that space too. 
I am sure supervised learning for video tasks will be a big pain in terms of labelling all the actions in the video, so you should also look into some techniques in unsupervised deep learning.